# Saving images faster on disk

Tags: python, multithreading, image, save, tiff

I have developed a  Python multi-thread program, one producer thread which acquires frames (512 x 640, 16uint) at high fps (around 75 fps), and two consumer-threads, one for real-time visualization and other for saving as 16-bit tiff. For each one of the consumers, I use a different queue.

Visualizing at real-time works fine, but saving takes so much time after the video is stoped ( even 20 seconds for a 2-minute recording). For saving, I used tifffile library or cv2, with similar performances.

**UPDATED info**

The images are gray-scale 16-bit numpy arrays directly placed in the queue, not compression, saved using tifffile.imsave. The second queue for visualization works properly on real-time, so saving must be the slowest process. I need to save each image independently, saving 3D is not an option for the time being. Using different threads for saving may ruin my acquisition order.

Is there any way, both in Python and/or OS (windows10) to accelerate the process, taking into account I need to save them in the same order they were recorded? I have a SSD 970 EVO disk drive

```
 class VideoGet():
          
            def __init__(self,input_dict,folder,record):
                self.handle=input_dict['handle']
                self.frame_t=input_dict['frametype']
                self.frameSize= input_dict['frameSize']
                # self.buffer = np.zeros(shape=(513,640), dtype=np.uint16)  
                self.record = record
                self.save = False
                self.done=False
                self.counter=0
                self.folder = folder
                
            def displayer(self,q2):
                
                while self.record is True:
                    if q2.empty() is True:
                        pass
                    else:
                        framedisplay = q2.get()
                        cv2.namedWindow("Video", cv2.WINDOW_NORMAL)
                        cv2.imshow("Video", framedisplay[:-1,:])   
    
                        cv2.waitKey(1)
                        q2.task_done()
    
                cv2.destroyAllWindows()         
         
                
            def consumer(self,q):
                data=[]
                 
                while True:
    
                        if q.empty():
                            time.sleep(0.002)
                            pass
    
                        else:
                                                    
                            frame_get = q.get()
                            if frame_get is None:                           
                                print('gone')
                                break
                            imsave(os.path.join(self.folder,(str(self.counter).zfill(5)+'.tiff')), frame_get[:-1,:])
                            if self.counter==0:
                                TS=1.0e-3 *struct.unpack('Q',(frame_get[-1,6:10]).tobytes())[0]
                            entr=[str(self.counter).zfill(5),str(round(1.0e3*(1.0e-3 *struct.unpack('Q',(frame_get[-1,6:10]).tobytes())[0]-TS)))]
                            data.append(entr) 
                                
                            self.counter=self.counter+1
                            q.task_done()                   
                     
                if data:
                      df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['Picture', 'Timestamp'])
                      df.to_csv(os.path.join(self.folder,'timestamps.txt'), header=False, index=False, sep=' ')
                      print('done')
                      self.done=True
    
    
                   
            def producer(self,buffer,q,q2):
                
                while self.record is True:
    
                   buffer=np.empty_like(buffer)            
                   if camera.properties.get_frame(self.handle,self.frame_t,4,buffer,self.frameSize)==0:
                       frame=buffer
                       q2.put(frame)
                       
                       if self.save is True:
                           q.put(frame)
    
                       del frame
    
                print('None')
                q.put(None)
    
            def run(self,buffer,q,q2):
                
                    prod_thread=Thread(target=self.producer,args=(buffer,q,q2,))
                    display_thread=Thread(target=self.displayer,args=(q2,))
                    con_thread= Thread(target=self.consumer, args=(q,))
                    
                    
                    prod_thread.start()
                    display_thread.start()
                    con_thread.start()
```

Comment: Please add more details. How do you use tifffile? Do you use compression? Do you know the number of images when creating the TIFF file? Successively appending uncompressed images using TiffWriter.save should be close to C stdlib I/O speed. Also make sure TIFF files are excluded from (for example) on-access virus scanning, indexing service, and explorer preview.

Comment: Please add more details. Are your images colour or greyscale? Have you tried running 2, 3 or 4 TIFF writer threads reading off a shared queue? Are you passing the whole image on the queue or just a buffer address which would be miles faster? Are you sure it is the TIFF writing which is slowing you down and not the queuing?

Comment: @cgohlke info updated

Comment: How would saving from two threads change the order of acquisition? Surely your acquisition thread acquires the images one after the other in order?

Comment: `tifffile.imsave` has a **lot** of overhead. I already mentioned that successively appending uncompressed images to the same file using `TiffWriter.save` should be as fast as it can get with tifffile.

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to say what's going wrong when you don't show your code. Also, it is not clear to me why the acquisition order would change if you have multiple writers.

Here is a script to generate synthetic frames the same size as your images and save them as TIFF files, in order. It scales up in speed pretty linearly with more writer threads:

```
NFRAMES      NWRITERS       TIME(s)
1000            1             1.48
1000            2             0.78
1000            4             0.48
```

---

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import time
import numpy as np
import threading, queue
from tifffile import imsave

def writer(q):
    print('[WRITER] Started')
    total = 0
    while True:
        (frameNum, im) = q.get()
        if frameNum < 0:
            break
        # Save as TIFF
        imsave(f'frame-{frameNum}.tif', im)
        total += 1
    print(f'[WRITER] Complete: wrote {total} frames')

if __name__ == "__main__":

    # Edit these to suit
    NFRAMES = 1000
    NWRITERS= 4

    # Create dummy image of correct size
    h, w = 640, 512
    im = np.random.randint(0, 65536, (h,w), dtype=np.uint16)

    # Create a queue to pass frames to writer(s)
    q = queue.Queue(16)

    print('[MAIN] Started')
    start = time.time()

    # Create and start writer thread(s)
    threads = []
    for _ in range(NWRITERS):
        t = threading.Thread(target=writer, args=(q,))
        t.start()
        threads.append(t)

    # Generate a large number of frames to store
    for frameNum in range(NFRAMES):
        # Put a tuple of frameNum and image in queue
        q.put((frameNum, im))

    # Sentinel to tell each writer to exit
    for _ in range(NWRITERS):
        q.put((-1,-1))

    # Wait for our writer thread(s) to exit
    for thread in threads:
       thread.join()

    elapsed = time.time() - start;
    print(f'[MAIN] Complete: {NFRAMES} frames, with {NWRITERS} writers in {elapsed} seconds')
```

---

**Sample Output**

```
[MAIN] Started
[WRITER] Started
[WRITER] Started
[WRITER] Started
[WRITER] Started
[WRITER] Complete: wrote 250 frames
[WRITER] Complete: wrote 250 frames
[WRITER] Complete: wrote 250 frames
[WRITER] Complete: wrote 250 frames
[MAIN] Complete: 1000 frames, with 4 writers in 0.4869719505310059 seconds
```

---

One thing I noticed, is that it runs about 10% faster if you replace `tifffile.imsave()` with:

```
np.save(f'frame-{frameNum}.npy', im)
```

Comment: the problem of using different threads is that I am also saving for each tiff file the timestamp ( which is encoded in the frame itself) and I referenced all those values to the very first one ( see code in my comment). I guess this would not be possible with different threads. I put some code below, my program is much bigger and includes connection to the camera. Also has a visualization option where the camera is shown but no frame is saved until specified with a tkinter button

Comment: Not sure I understand what you are saying about timestamps and ordering. Are you trying to timestamp the time of acquisition - if so, grab it when you acquire the frame and pass it to the writer as a tuple like I pass the frame number. If you are trying to timestamp the writing to disk, grab it in the writer thread when you write it.

Comment: Each frame contains its (acquisition) timestamp encoded in the last row of pixels , so I am passing the full array and then I retrieve that time stamp during saving. Thus I save each frame and (at the end) a big txt containing frame name and its corresponding timestamp, but referenced ( my 0 value) to first saved image ( see the list data in my question code and variable TS)

Comment: So why can't you retrieve the last line of the frame if you have 2 or more writer threads?

Comment: yes, of course, retrieving that value is not a problem. What I am concerned is that the variable TS ( timestamp of first saved image) and the data list would not be accessible for all the threads or the concatenation of list data would fail?